# Number check in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to check in 10 digit number whether it contain 999 or 000 in the 4-6th bytes ?

I have a n idea with using INSTR but i don't know how to execute it

Comment: if it's numeric, something like ```(col % 1000000)/1000``` could work (adjust the numbers (powers of 10) according to your digit counting method). If it's a string, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is strange.  If the "number" is really a string, then you can use `like` or `substr()`:

```
where col like '___999%' or col like '___000%'
```

or:

```
where substr(col, 4, 3) in ('999', '000')
```

or even regular expressions.

Given the nature of your question, you can turn a number into a string and use these methods. However, if you are looking at particular digits, then the "number" should be stored as a string.

Answer (score 0):

If they are actually numbers rather than strings then you could use numeric manipulation:

```
with t (n) as (
            select 1234567890 from dual
  union all select 1239997890 from dual
  union all select 1230007890 from dual
  union all select 1299967890 from dual
  union all select 1234000890 from dual
)
select n,
  mod(n, 10000000) as stage1,
  mod(n, 10000000)/10000 as stage2,
  trunc(mod(n, 10000000)/10000) as stage3,
  case when trunc(mod(n, 10000000)/10000) in (0, 999) then 'Yes' else 'No' end as matches
from t;

         N     STAGE1     STAGE2     STAGE3 MATCHES
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------
1234567890    4567890    456.789        456 No     
1239997890    9997890    999.789        999 Yes    
1230007890       7890       .789          0 Yes    
1299967890    9967890    996.789        996 No     
1234000890    4000890    400.089        400 No
```

Stage 1 effectively strips off the first three digits. Stage two almost strips off the last four digits, but leaves fractions, so stage 3 adds `trunc()` (you could also use `floor()`) to ignore those fractional parts.

The result of that is the numeric value of the 4-6th digits, and you can then test if that is 0, 999 or something else.

This is really looking at the 4th to 6th most significant digits, which is the same if the number is always 10 digits; if it might actually have different numbers of digits then you'd need to clarify what you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

select 
 1  from dual where instr(98800054542,000,4,3)in (6) or instr(98800054542,999,4,3)in (6); let me know if this helped.